# What does 'noun+の+ほかに' mean?

Tags: grammar, meaning

> お知らせ [今日は日本の授業がありません 私の女の子が熱が痛いですから... 学生たちのほかに調べてくださいね...お願いします...明日宿題は学校の後でSMP Regularの事務所でMr.Jayに取ってください. 月曜日Mr.Jayに出してください.] と私の先生が書いたのです.

It turns out that in "学生たちのほかに調べてください", my teacher wanted to say "please tell the other students". So it should be 教える not 調べる. However this context is only dedicated to my initial question.  What is the meaning of 'noun + の + ほか + に'?

Comment: I can't understand What 学生たちのほかに調べてくださいね means. You should ask your teacher this meaning.

Comment: 今日は日本の授業がありません。→ 日本語の授業がありません。

Comment: 「Mr.Jayに取ってください」 looks incorrect, too...

Comment: @chocolate should it be Mr.Jayから取ってください?

Comment: I'd say 「Mr.Jayから受け取ってください」or「Mr.Jayに/からもらってください」

Comment: @chocolate It turns out that my teacher wanted to say "please tell the other students" in the "学生たちのほかに調べてください". Isn't it suppose to be 教える? What does "noun + の + ほかに" mean?(since this is my INITIAL QUESTION, not the meaning of the that phrase)

Comment: @Dekiru Maybe you teacher meant to type/say しゃべる and not 調{しら}べる which can sound quit similar (at least to me). As for you question ほか simply means _other_. The の before it is needed if what precedes it is a noun, the に is just the particle に , here marking who is being/or should be talked to. ほかに as an adverb can also mean in addition to or besides, but I don't see that being correct here. 学生たちのほか: the other students.

Comment: @Christer since the verb 伝える and 教える are transitive, can I say 学生たちの他を伝えてください  with を particle?

Comment: "please tell the other students" <- I think your teacher meant to say **ほかの**学生たちに**知らせて**ください。 (しら**せ**る, not しら**べ**る.) "To the other students" should be ほかの学生たちに, not 学生たちのほかに.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"please tell the other students" is translated as 他の生徒に伝えてください.

～の他に means "besides", "in addition to". For example, この本の他に、好きな本はありますか?( Are there your favorite books besides this book), 私の他に好きな人はいるの?(Do you have special someone besides me?).

And even if it is 学生たちの他に伝えてください, I feel it is a bit unnatural.

Comment: "I feel it is unnatural" --> how so? Which grammatical part seems off or is it grammatically correct? Can I change the に with を?

Comment: 学生たちの他を伝えてください doesn't make sense. I don't know whether it is grammatically correct or not but  we say 他の生徒に伝えてください.　And 他の生徒 means "other students", 生徒の他に means "besides students".

Comment: So saying 他のnoun means other noun(s) while nounの他に means beside noun(s)?

Comment: Yes, I think so.